# lcdui vs lwuit command difference

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, lcdui

i am used to working with lcdui interface but i want to work with lwuit interface.
Can any one tell me the different command list.

```
  package newpackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.microedition.midlet.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.plaf.UIManager;
import com.sun.lwuit.util.Resources;

public class test extends MIDlet implements ActionListener {
Form mainform;
List list;
Command exit = new Command ("Exit");



 public void startApp() {

        Display.init(this);
        try {
  Resources r = Resources.open("/res/javaTheme.res");
  UIManager.getInstance().setThemeProps(r.getTheme("javaTheme"));
} catch (IOException ioe) {
 // Do something here.
}
        mainform = new Form("MENU");
        list = new List();
        list.addItem("Remitting");
        list.addItem("Paying");
        list.addItem("Change Pin");
        list.addItem("Inbox");

        mainform.addComponent(list);
        mainform.show();
        mainform.addCommand(exit);
        mainform.setCommandListener(this);




 }

 public void pauseApp() {}

 public void destroyApp(boolean unconditional) {}

 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

 if (ae.getCommand()== exit){
    destroyApp(false);
    notifyDestroyed();
   }

 if (ae.getSource()==list){
  switch(list.getSelectedIndex()){
   case 0:
       Remitting();
        break;
   case 1:
       Paying();
       break;
   case 2:
       Changepin();
       break;
   case 3:
       Inbox();
       break;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding into List. List not a Command. Both are different. Read this article, [Introduction about LWUIT](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javame/lwuit_intro/).

Comment: I want to display the corresponding form on selecting the particular list item... I have done it in LCDUI but not getting it in  LWUIT..

Comment: `addActionListener` to the list.

Comment: For more info see [this sample code.](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/38461/1763?supportItem=1)